# Parse response using Jackson

Tags: java, jackson, jaxb, jaxb2, jackson-databind

I am trying to parse the api response using Jackson. getting errors like com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "Health"

I have tried options like

```
objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE, false); //with true
```

I think simple mistake but not able to figure out. please help

Response json:

```
{
  "Health": {
    "id": "abc_Server",
    "name": "ABC Request Service",
    "status": "GREEN",
    "dependencies": [
      {
        "id": "DB",
        "name": "MySQL",
        "message": "Connection successful.",
        "status": "GREEN"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

java pojos

```
@JsonRootName(value = "Health")
public class HealthResponse {

  private String id;
  private String name;
  private String status;
  private List<Dependencies> dependencies;

  //getter and setter methods
  }
}


public class Dependencies {

  private String id;
  private String name;
  private String message;
  private String status;
  //getter and setter methods
}
```

main class:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
try {
InputStream response = healthCheckWebTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(InputStream.class);
HealthResponse healthResponse = objectMapper.readValue(response, HealthResponse.class);
}catch(Exception e){
  //
}
```

Also tried have a pojo with but did not work

```
@JsonRootName(value = "Health")
public class Health {

  private HealthResponse health;

 //getter and setter
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When converting JSON to Java object you're actually deserializing, not serializing. So use this:

```
objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
```

Complete code that's currently working for me (prints abc_Server):

```
    String json="{\"Health\":{\"id\":\"abc_Server\",\"name\":\"ABCRequestService\",\"status\":\"GREEN\",\"dependencies\":[{\"id\":\"DB\",\"name\":\"MySQL\",\"message\":\"Connectionsuccessful.\",\"status\":\"GREEN\"}]}}";

    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
    try {
        HealthResponse healthResponse = objectMapper.readValue(json, HealthResponse.class);
        System.out.println(healthResponse.getId());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And `HealthResponse`:

```
@JsonRootName(value = "Health")
class HealthResponse {
    [...]
}
```

No change in `Dependencies`

Documentation for [UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationFeature.html#UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE).

Comment: I tried this but getting below error.
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Root name 'Health' does not match expected ('HealthResponse') for type [simple type, class com.xas.connector.dto.HealthResponse]
 at [Source: (org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.EntityInputStream); line: 1, column: 2]

Comment: Works fine for me. Don't use the outer class Health. Put the JsonRootName annotation on HealthResponse directly, and read HealthResponse from ObjectMapper.

Comment: I've updated the answer with the full code that works for me. If it still doesn't work for you: a) Check if the json you're actually getting is the same as what you've posted in the question AND b) post your jackson version, so that I can try to replicate with that. My version is 2.8.5. Perhaps you can also try upgrading to that version.

Comment: I guess may be something wrong with InputStream response = xxx
objectMapper.readValue(response, xyz) .  i will have to check this.

Comment: Try draining the inputstream into a string, print the string and pass the string to ObjectMapper instead of inputstream.

Comment: Thank you Vasan. I tried changing inputstream to string then it worked.
 String myString = IOUtils.toString(response, "UTF-8");
        healthResponse = objectMapper.readValue(myString, HealthResponse.class);